# Problem updating new version apk to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, store

I created an app in Appinventor2. It is listed on Google Play and I originally mistakenly **included the version number** in the app name "Well_Red_controller_V29".

The Play store seems to have changed the app name to include the development platform (appinventor) and my Google name (doodooronron).

I have since updated it twice, but when I tried to upload the latest version (V32), the App Releases window returns the error message

> "Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name 
>   appinventor.ai_Doodooronron.Well_Red_controller_V29."

I have tried using this name as well as the original name of the app and various other permutations, but nothing seems to work and I keep getting the same reply.

Does anyone please have any idea what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It just occurred to me that my method of versioning the apps by saving each updated project with an incrementing name (the latest was Well_Red_controller_V32) then building it to an app, then changing the app name to the original uploaded one is the wrong way to go about it.
So I just now tried saving the latest version of the **project** with the original uploaded name (Well_Red_controller_V29) then built the apk file from that.  And bingo! it uploaded OK.
It's obvious to me now that the project name is embedded in the apk file and so the project name should never be changed to create different versions.
In future, if I want to keep a particular version, I will save the project with a unique name containing the version number then revert back to the original project to build the latest version.  Either that, or download the aia file to my HDD and keep only one project.